# jQuery select all elements that follow or preeced an element with a given class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a jQuery css selector treat for tha savvy ones.

I'm having a table with a sequence of rows such as the one shown below:

```
<tr>
    <td class="disabled"><a href="#"><span>1</span></a></td>
    <td class="disabled"><a href="#"><span>2</span></a></td>
    <td class="disabled"><a href="#"><span>3</span></a></td>
    <td class="disabled"><a href="#"><span>4</span></a></td>
    <td class="selected"><a href="#"><span>5</span></a></td>
    <td class="selected"><a href="#"><span>5</span></a></td>
    <td class="selected"><a href="#"><span>6</span></a></td>
    <td class="disabled"><a href="#"><span>4</span></a></td>
    <td class="disabled"><a href="#"><span>4</span></a></td>
    <td class="selected"><a href="#"><span>5</span></a></td>
    <td class="selected"><a href="#"><span>5</span></a></td>
    <td class="selected"><a href="#"><span>6</span></a></td>
    <td class="disabled"><a href="#"><span>4</span></a></td>
</tr>
```

I need to add a class e.g. 'checkin', on all td.selected that immediately follow td.disabled, but also I need to add class 'checkout' on all td.selected that preceed td.disabled. Result should come up like this:

```
<tr>
    <td class="disabled"><a href="#"><span>1</span></a></td>
    <td class="disabled"><a href="#"><span>2</span></a></td>
    <td class="disabled"><a href="#"><span>3</span></a></td>
    <td class="disabled"><a href="#"><span>4</span></a></td>
    <td class="selected checkin"><a href="#"><span>5</span></a></td>
    <td class="selected"><a href="#"><span>5</span></a></td>
    <td class="selected checkout"><a href="#"><span>6</span></a></td>
    <td class="disabled"><a href="#"><span>4</span></a></td>
    <td class="disabled"><a href="#"><span>4</span></a></td>
    <td class="selected checkin"><a href="#"><span>5</span></a></td>
    <td class="selected"><a href="#"><span>5</span></a></td>
    <td class="selected checkout"><a href="#"><span>6</span></a></td>
    <td class="disabled"><a href="#"><span>4</span></a></td>
</tr>
```

Any ideas,

Thanks

Comment: You describe something different in your text, but the code could be achieved using [`$('.selected:first')`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) and [`$('.selected:last')`](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK this cannot be done with a CSS selector for the "checkin" class, because you cannot reference the *preceding* elemen in the selector (it can be done for the other half though).

However, you can do this with judicious use of `.filter`:

```
$(".selected").filter(function() { return $(this).prev(".disabled").length; })
              .addClass("checkin").end()
              .filter(function() { return $(this).next(".disabled").length; })
              .addClass("checkout");
```

**[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/atBW6/1)**.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) and [prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/), respectively, filtering the siblings through the selector your specify:

```
$("td.disabled").next(".selected").addClass("checkin").end()
                .prev(".selected").addClass("checkout");
```

Comment: thanks a lot, resolved quite a bit of my troubles, it seems that I can't accept both yours and Jons answer, but for the sake of others both work well.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("tr td.selected:first-child").addClass("checkin");
$("tr td.selected:last-child").addClass("chechout");
```

Comment: That only selects the first and last td with .selected class. Not the ones that are preceded or followed by items with .disabled class.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. You'd need a selector for selected blocks, and then apply first/last-child.

Comment: Exactly, and that is what makes it tricky by my opinion. In my case I can have td.disabled, td.selected sequences switching multiple times, I will edit the example in the question as I think that this can't be achieved (or at least I can't figure it out) by using first, last, first-child, last-child

Comment: I'd go with Jon's or Frédéric Hamidi's approach. Since you can't select predecessors with CSS, you're better of using jQuery's prev/next for both borders of the selected blocks.